# How to properly write Unit Tests for Input and Output Functions

Tags: unit-testing

I'm new to writing unit tests and i am trying to figure out the best way to implement Unit Tests when you have a function that stores data in some way and another function that retrieves that data. For example:

```
def save_data( data ):
    _write_to_file( _serialize( data ) )

def get_data():
    return _parse_data( _read_file() )
```

To test the save_data() function i know i could read the file and see if it is correct but what if in the future the way the output is formatted changes. As long as get_data() is changed as well the public interface could be exactly the same but the unit test will fail. Is it normal for unit tests to fail even if nothing is wrong?

Also, I could just test save_data() and get_data() in the same unit test but I've read that you shouldn't test two functions in the same test.

What am i missing here? Is this just a sign that this code is badly design? If so what is wrong with kind of design?

Answer (score 0):

Though definitions vary, generally, unit tests verify *the behavior of a unit in isolation*.

Isolation means independently of other portions of code and **free of side effects**. In most cases, it wouldn't make much sense to unit test code that is doing IO. Those type of tests are sometimes referred to as integration tests (again, definitions vary).

This is especially true if these functions are an implementation detail, meaning you could be storing/retrieving your data in a different way without changing the behavior.

The code in the example that you provide is in fact susceptible of being *mocked* or otherwise replaced by a *test double* when you are unit testing the code that **uses** the code in your example.

> [...] you shouldn't test two functions in the same test.

This is mostly incorrect. A "unit" is a *unit of behavior*. It does not imply a single function (or even a single class in OOP). It is true that a test should only verify one aspect or behavior, but that might require more than one function call and there is nothing wrong with that.